# styled-components typescript error with Material-UI component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

Using typescript and want to set styling for Material UI component with styled-components.
But type error happens with StyledComponent showing `Type '{ children: string; }' is missing the following properties`

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'; // ^4.1.3
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'; // ^3.9.1

class TestForm extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Button style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>Work</Button>{/* OK  */}

        <StyledButton>Doesn't work</StyledButton>{/* Type Error happens here <=============== */}
        {/**
          Type '{ children: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Pick<(ButtonProps & RefAttributes<Component<ButtonProps, any, any>>) | (ButtonProps & { children?: ReactNode; }), "form" | "style" | "title" | "disabled" | "mini" | ... 279 more ... | "variant"> & Partial<...>, "form" | ... 283 more ... | "variant">': style, classes, className, innerRef [2739]
         */}
      </>
    );
  }
}

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  background: blue;
`;

export default TestForm;
```

It is showing children prop is missing.
I have tried the following too but still doesn't work.

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)<{ children: string; }>`
  background: blue;
`;
```

Does anyone know how to use Material UI with styled-components in typescript?

Answer (score 14):

I'm also getting this error with `material-ui` **v3.9.3** and `styled-components` **v4.2.0**, the latest versions at the time of posting this answer.

My workaround for this is the following

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Button, { ButtonProps } from '@material-ui/core/Button'

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  background: blue;
` as React.ComponentType<ButtonProps>
```

This casts `StyledButton` to the same type as the Material UI `Button`. It removes the error and gives you the same type checking as you get for `Button`. In most cases this is all you want.

In cases where you need additional props to use in the styles, and want to enforce they are passed, you can just extend `ButtonProps` and cast to that custom type:

```
type StyledButtonProps = ButtonProps & { background: string }

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  background: ${(props: StyledButtonProps) => props.background};
` as React.ComponentType<StyledButtonProps>


const MyComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <StyledButton size='small' background='blue'>one</StyledButton>

    // ERROR HERE - forgot the 'background' prop
    <StyledButton size='small'>two</StyledButton>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: The author commented with the following workaround and said that it's suppose to be solved with the upcoming version 4: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13921#issuecomment-484133463

Answer (score 0):

This was working fine a few months ago, but I just started a new project and am having the same issue. Must be a problem with the more recent versions.

Horrible, I know, but in the meantime maybe best to:

```
const StyledButton: any = styled(Button)`
  background: blue;
`;
```