# Material UI CSS-in-JS typing

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, material-ui, css-in-js

I'm setting up a project using React, React Admin, Babel, TypeScript and Webpack. The editor I'm using is VSCode.

I'm trying to use the [new Material UI styling solution](https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/) and then specifically the Styled Components API.

I've TSLint configured so that's required to add a `typedef` to a variable declaration.

When I write the following code:

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)({
  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  height: 10,
  width: 80,
});
```

TSLint throws the following error: `expected variable-declaration: 'StyledButton' to have a typedef (typedef)tslint(1)`. Please note that the `Button` I'm passing to `styled()` is a component coming from Material UI:

`import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';`

When I then hover over `StyledButton` I see the following:

[image]

So basically VSCode is telling me the type of `StyledButton` variable, which is `React.ComponentType`. So if I update my code to this:

```
const StyledButton: React.ComponentType = styled(Button)({
  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  height: 10,
  width: 80,
});
```

I get no errors whatsoever. Great!

But now my issue begins: when I change the `Button` to an actual HTML element `button`:

```
const StyledButton: React.ComponentType = styled('button')({
  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  height: 10,
  width: 80,
});
```

My editor throws the following error:

```
Type 'ComponentType<never>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}>'.
  Type 'ComponentClass<never, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}>'.
    Type 'ComponentClass<never, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>'.
      Types of property 'getDerivedStateFromProps' are incompatible.
        Type 'GetDerivedStateFromProps<never, any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'GetDerivedStateFromProps<{}, any> | undefined'.
          Type 'GetDerivedStateFromProps<never, any>' is not assignable to type 'GetDerivedStateFromProps<{}, any>'.
            Types of parameters 'nextProps' and 'nextProps' are incompatible.
              Type 'Readonly<{}>' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

When I remove the `typedef` and hover over `StyledButton` again I see the following:

[image]

So VSCode is telling me that the type has changed to `React.ComponentType<never>`. Lets update my code to:

```
const StyledButton: React.ComponentType<never> = styled('button')({
  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  height: 10,
  width: 80,
});
```

And the errors go away, nice! Let's use the `StyledButton`:

```
<StyledButton>
  I'm a button
</StyledButton>
```

This throws another error:

```
This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects type 'never' which requires multiple children, but only a single child was provided.ts(2745)
```

Am I doing something wrong or? How can I correctly type the `StyledButton` and not got errors when I actually use the component?

I also posted this issue on GitHub but it got closed unfortunately: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14898

If you need any more information please let me know and thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a repro code? preferably a github repository with the exact same versions you have for @material-ui/core and styles. Also what version of typescript do you have?

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://github.com/patrick91/Styled-Components-Typescript-Example/blob/master/src/components/section.tsx), where there is an example on how to declare a react styled component in typescript.

Comment: @MarioSantini this is not using Styled Components, it's using the new Material UI styling API

Comment: @DavidWorldpeace you're right, I'm not an expert in Typescript, but I think the example I posted is meningful, have a look to this answer I found just right now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509851/styled-components-typescript-error-with-material-ui-component I think you're mixing HOC with styled component... But I'm not so sure about this, sorry.